# Why does my nginx proxy fail, but my node.js proxy works?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, node.js, ajax

I am trying to setup an nginx server to reverse proxy data from two different servers via ajax. Only one of the requests is working however.
The other gives me a *No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header* error.

Running the same front-end that does the ajax requests on a node.js server works however:

```
"use strict";
let express = require('express');
let request = require('request');

let PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
let app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/a", (req, res) => {
        let url = "http://external-website-a.com/rest.exe/etc?...";
        request(url).pipe(res);
});

app.get("/b", (req, res) => {
        let url = "http://external-website-b.com/webservice.svc/etc?...";
        request(url).pipe(res);
});

let server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log("Listening on port: " + PORT);
});
```

With node.js the client gets both json files, while **"b"** fails on nginx.
Here is my sites-available/default config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html

        server_name _;

        location / {
                sendfile off; #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37742950
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /a {
                proxy_pass http://external-website-a.com/rest.exe/etc?...;
        }

        location /b {
                proxy_pass http://external-website-b.com/webservice.svc/etc?...;
        }
}
```

I have been trying to add all the **proxy_set_header** information I could find on the web.. but nothing has worked so far..
Furthermore when I directly access "*localhost:8080/a*" I get shown a json (as I should), but when I access "*localhost:8080/b*" I instead get redirected to "*external-website-b.com/webservice.svc/etc?...*" even with **proxy_redirect off;** Why? And does that mean anything related to the issue?

How come my node.js/express server can serve the data, but nginx fails?

Answer (score 0):

proxy_set_header  Access-Control-allow-Origin "*" .  add this in nginx configuration(inside all location directive )